# Pinia not reflecting value until reload

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, pinia

Below code renames and cuts out other stuff to keep as succinct as I can....

I need to get the stored_value in the detail page which the router link is going to take you to, when clicked. That value can not appear in the address bar. I therefore set/update the value into session storage on the same click you make to go to the detail page so it can be obtained there. (It is the result in the loop of results which you are clicking, which dictate the value stored)

A have a Pinia store which obtains a value from session storage:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', {
    state: () => {
        return { value: sessionStorage.getItem("stored_value") }
    }
})
```

I loop over results using a search result component:

```
<SearchResult v-for="item in allResults" :key="item" :item_value="item.some_value"/ >
```

The SearchResult component:

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useMyStore } from '../stores/MyStore'

const props = defineProps({
    some_value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
})

const my_store = useMyStore
const chosen_value = ref(my_store.value)
const item_value = ref(props.item_value)

function updateChosenValue() {
    chosen_value.value = some_value.value
    sessionStorage.setItem("stored_value", some_value.value)
}
</script>
    
<template>
    <div class="result">
        <RouterLink @click="updateChosenValue" :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {some: params} ">
            <h2 class="item">{{ props.title }}</h2>
        </RouterLink>
    </div>
</template>
```

On the detail page:

Does work:
`console.log('value',sessionStorage.getItem("stored_value"))`

Returns null until page reload:

```
import { useMyStore } from '../stores/MyStore';
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const my_store = useMyStore()
console.log('my store', my_store)

const val = ref(my_store.value)
console.log('my store val', val)

const { value } = storeToRefs(my_store);
console.log('value',value)
```

I know I could just say, hey I can get from session storage so whatever just carry on, but I would like to keep code consistent throughout the project, in addition to just really wanting to know why it's not working as expected, particularly when I can just call session storage directly on the detail page and it works, and that's the same thing I am doing in the store.

I also added a watcher but that never fires, I expect because the value has already changed by the time the detail page is hit.